# NetCDF-Fortran: Build library (Windows)

Tags: build, fortran, netcdf, netcdf4

I'm a new user of NetCDF, and I would like to use this file structure in my **cross-platform Fortran-2008 projects.**

### The C Library dependency:

So, first **I downloaded the NetCDF-C binary installer**, that is described as a NetCDF-Fortran library dependency, and installed it in my machine.

**Link:** [NetCDF4+DAP (x64)](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/winbin.html)

After that I added the NetCDF installed folder path to the Windows 10 environment path.

I tested it running the `ncdump` in the Windows console and it **works good!**

### The Fortran Library:

Second, I cloned the **NetCDF-Fortran** Github repositore and:

**a)** I opened the Windows console and went to the cloned folder

**b)** I created a new folder called: "build"

**c)** I entered in this "build" folder and typed: `cmake ..`

Then the CMake complete **all stuffs ok**:
[image]

This CMake process generated 54 Microsoft Visual Studio projects and one Solution file inside the "build" folder.

So, I opened the **NC4F solution**, and I right-clicked in the solution name and I clicked in the **"Build" option.** I expected Visual Studio to generate static `(*.lib)` and dynamic `(*.dll)` **Fortran library output files**.

VS starts to compile the solution, but it gave to me **a lot of compile-time erros.** Here is my print screen:

[image]

**What I'm doing wrong?**

How can I get the **NetCDF-Fortran libraries** (static and dynamic) to use them in my Fortran-08 projects?

**My system is:**

- Windows 10 x64
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2019
- Intel Visual Fortran 2019

Thank you,

Comment: Facing similar issues, would appreciate any guidance if you managed to solve it!